# Methods/Functions/ .h and .m files

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, objective-c++

I want to create an .h and .m files @property to get latitude and longitude and then RETURN these values - how is it best to be done ? I can create a method that sends variables and then returns variables but I don't want to send any variables - just recieving the lat/long. Hows is this best to be done ? Is it best to create an .m and .h file or is it best to create an method ? If so can you provide me with some sample code.

Thanks a lot Jason

Comment: I am asking this because I want to make my code very neat indeed and not just a long list of commands. I have done some stuff on this but I don't want to send variables to a methods, just receive two long variables (lat and long) from the method.

Comment: if you want to get the users location. Core Location methods will do all this for you. I suggest you look at the developer docs.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Its so confusing what you are even asking.

Comment: Can you at least include in your question an example of the kind of thing you're after?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to wrap lat/long values in one property.

You'll need to `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>`

Comment: Thanks all, I know how to do the function itself but I don't know how to split it from the ViewDidLoad function, to make it look better or shall I create external .h and .m files. if so how is it done ? thanks so far.

Comment: You really need to go through some iOS tutorials if you are asking that... it's just too confusing, I can't even tell what you are asking.